# Wordpress e Google Analytics: como evitar contagem de área administrativa?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

Como configurar o Código do Google Analytics de modo a evitar que os acesso de administradores ou de autores às áreas administrativas do Wordpress sejam contadas?

Comment: como você instalou o código? Usando um plugin? Colando o script nas paginas?

Comment: Utilizo um plugin

Comment: Seu plugin deve ter uma página de administração em que vc seleciona se quer ou não rastrear as páginas/ações de administradores. Sem mais detalhes é tudo que dá pra te dizer.

Comment: Mas minha intenção é fazer isso no código do javascript. Porque assim, não fico na dependência do plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer fazer isso na mão, aqui vai:

1. Instale o plugin https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/
2. Insira na aba Footer:

   ```
   <? if (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   ...GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE...
   <? } ?>
   ```

Comment: Leonel, para entender: o comando <? (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?> é um php que nega a leitura do Google-Analytics se o  "user" estiver logado no painel administrativo. É isso?

Comment: Exato @EdmarRobertoPrandini!

Comment: Só para informar, sua sugestão não funcionou.

Comment: Ainda precisa de uma mão com isso? Tente validar se está chamando ou não com a extensão do chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: Na verdade, solucionei parcialmente criando um filtro para /wp-admin/ na administração do GA. Mas, páginas visitadas pelos administradores fora do wp-admin serão registradas, o que eu pretendia que não fossem calculadas.

Comment: Você pode adicionar a tag do Google pelo seu **footer.php**:

<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in()) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

GA code    

</script>

  <?php } ?>

Referência: https://www.doitwithwp.com/exclude-admins-from-google-analytics-on-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Muito provavelmente o plugin que você utiliza já tem essa opção.
Eu utilizo o Yoast SEO, considerado um dos melhores do mercado, e ele já possui essa opção para impedir contagem de administradores.

Comment: Onde? Como configurar?

Comment: Qual o plugin você utiliza? Só queria fazer uma correção que o Yoast Analytics se tornou o Monster Insights Analytics. Para editar você acessa o menu na barra lateral esquerda nessa sequência.
Insights > Settings > Tracking > Ignore these user roles from tracking:
Aqui você pode adicionar as posições que você não quer que sejam contadas. Usando o Monster Insights Analytics, antigo Yoast Analytics.